Mobile Hotspot toggle is disabled / greyed out. How to share phone's data connection to laptop over WiFi?
I have working mobile data on my Samsung Galaxy A24. I am trying to share mobile data to my laptop over Wifi. I guess this is called Wi-Fi tethering.
In Settings, there is an option for Mobile Hotspot under the "Mobile Hotspot and tethering" section, but the toggle of Mobile Hotspot is greyed out.
What can I do to enable it?

Was the phone sold by a mobile network operator or in a regular [internet] shop? MNO devices often have "adapted" firmware, disabling hotspot feature could be one of those.

@Robert Thank you! The phone itself was bought  in another country in a regular shop . The SIM was bought  from the operator.

Have you looked into this option: SecureTether WiFi?
